# Ajax post says undefined laravel 6

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, post

I'm trying to update my DB with AJAX once there are some changes, but I seem to miss something.

My controller:

```
    // Update dates
public function updateDates(Request $request)
{
    // dd($input);
    $event = new Event();
    $event->invoice = $request->input('invoice');
    $event->paid = $request->input('paid');
    $event->save();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

Routes:

```
    //Events
Route::resource('event', 'EventController');
Route::post('/updateDates', ['as' => 'updateDates', 'uses' => 'EventController@updateDates']);
```

Jquery:

```
 $('.datepickerstart').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var update_id = $(this).data('evid');
        var invoice = $("input[name=invoice_date]").val();
        var payment = $("input[name=payment_date]").val();

        console.log(update_id, invoice, payment);

        $.ajax({
           method:'post',
           url:'{{ route("updateDates") }}',
           dataType:'JSON',
           data: { 
                id : update_id,
                invoice : invoice,
                paid : payment 
            },
           success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.success);

            }
        });        
});
```

I do console log correct data before ajax post. Cannot even dd() request in my controller, what am I doing wrong?

Console error:

> VM4649:1 POST http://localhost:8000/updateDates 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

I was getting "undefined" erlier.

UPDATE: solved, after looking through the logs. I was creating new objects instead of updating them and got error: no default field value

Comment: Q: Which is your top priority: the "undefined" error in your JS ... or the HTTP 500 error on the server?  Q: Any idea what's causing the HTTP 500 error?  Q: Can you post the relevant server logs showing the server-side error?

Comment: Thanks, helped after looking through the logs

Answer (score 2):

Add csrf field in your data post like this :

```
data: { 
   id : update_id,
   invoice : invoice,
   paid : payment,
   _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' 
},
```